# Creating multiple dynamic drop down using databases in php

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys i was developing a small project for my college and this consists of a table that a prizeid, prizename from a table called prizemaster and names of candidates that can be nominated by staffs from a table called studentmaster. here is my php code :

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM prizemaster");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM studentmaster");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Prize ID &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</th>
    <th>Prize Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    <th>Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prizeid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><select>";
    while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    echo "<option>" . $drop['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

the table was successfully created but there seems to a problem. in my first record the drop down is fine but in all other records the drop down is empty. how to i solve this? can anyone explain clearly with code as am new to php.

here is what my problem looks like:

```
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/820x321q90/838/yj63.png
```

Comment: First thing u need <option value="aa">aa</option> , second thing u need to make sure ur query is returning more than one value

Comment: Always view html source for the failed (looking) page too, sometimes you might be surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the issue

You are executing 2 query on the top and when looping through the first query and inside that looping the second query.

The problem is when you loop the 2nd query inside the first the cursor of the 2nd is set to the end and on next iteration of first the 2nd will get nothing

you may need to use [mysqli_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prizeid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><select>";
    while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo "<option>" . $drop['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($result1, 0);
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Hey please dont use Sir to address me !! I am not big to be address with Sir !!

Comment: anyone who knows above me is referred to as sir!!

Comment: But its really heavy weighted and I would prefer to reserve this for people who deserve it and I am certainly not :)

Answer (score 0):

Code indentation is important! Your problem is the nested while loop.

```
while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
```

After it's done the first time there will be no more results to fetch. What you can do is save the results to an array outside of the first while loop

```
$ddOptions = array();
while($drop = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    $ddOptions[] = $drop;
```

then loop through the array in the other while

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['prizeid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><select>";
    foreach($ddOptions as $drop)
    {
        echo "<option>" . $drop['name'] . "</option>";
    }
echo "</select></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: i can understand what ur trying to explain me sir but i am unable to figure out the correct code to get it done. can u give me the code?

Comment: replace the bottom section of code with my revised version of yours and put the code i posted with the $ddOptions array before the first while loop. basically replace your code from the first while loop down with all my code except the first bit.